# ion-loading cant be manually dismissed using the backdrop on iOS

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

Im using Ionic `v7` together with Angular and im not able to use the `backdropDismiss` property provided by the `LoadingController`. I have tested the behavior on the browser, Android and iOS and the misbehavior is only present on iOS. The `LoadingController` is injected into a service and consumed from within the service. Here is a minimal code:

```js
import { inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Injectable()
export class MyTestService {
  private readonly loadingController = inject(LoadingController);

  showLoading(): void {
    const loadingController = this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'loading',
      spinner: 'dots',
      showBackdrop: true,
      backdropDismiss: true,
    }).then((element) => void element.present());
  }
}
```

How can I achieve the default ionic backdrop behavior similar to how it is present in android and the web? I have tried already setting a custom css class for `ion-loading` as it was presented as a solution for lower versions of ionic, however it did not help.

`components.scss:`

```scss
ion-loading.backdrop-workaround {
  --height: auto;
}
```

Then adding the custom class to my loading instance:

```
const loadingController = this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'loading',
      spinner: 'dots',
      showBackdrop: true,
      backdropDismiss: true,
      cssClass: 'backdrop-workaround',  // did not help for iOS
    });
```

Comment: You should you inline loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to the `LoadingController`. When I switched to the inline method, the backdrop worked.

Sample could taken from the docs:

```html
<ion-button id="open-loading">Show Loading</ion-button>
<ion-loading trigger="open-loading" message="loading"></ion-loading>
```